# Assigning a lambda to an Action<T>

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, action

It is known possible to assign a lambda that returns no value to an `Action<T>` object. How about lambdas that do theoretically return a value? Like this one:

```
Action<double> result = (x => x + 1);
```

Will the result just be ignored?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use a [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647.aspx)

```
Func<double, double> result = (x => x + 1);
```

If you write it like this then the result can be ignored. Although this example is not terribly useful

```
Action<double> result = x => { x + 1; };
```